# vimscript replace line not working

Tags: vim

Newcomer to VimL trying to write a mapping that does the following:

```
foo
|----> cursor
bar
baz
```

`lr2j` should repalce `foo` with `baz`.

```
" replace the current line with a line given by a linewise motion
function! s:LineReplace(type)
  if a:type !=# 'line'
    return
  endif
  let saved_register = @@
  silent execute "normal! S\<esc>my`]dd'yPjddk^ :delmarks y"
  let @@ = saved_register
endfunction
nnoremap lr :set operatorfunc=<SID>LineReplace<cr>g@
```

Instead I get

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>108_LineReplace: line 5: E20: Mark not set
```

I've tried different permutations of `execute "normal! ..."` command to no avail. Can anyone spot the error?

I should note that when I test out the `normal` commands everything works fine and the mark `'y` exists.

Comment: Looks like you mark a line and remove it right after that. That first `dd` kills the mark.

Comment: From the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks), it looks like `']` is _jump to beginning/end of previously changed or yanked text_. I've been using it to grab the end position of a motion. But the end of a motion isn't "previously changed or yanked text"...

Comment: It stores range for more than change operators, so the use is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:move` and `:delete` to simply things:

```
" replace the current line with a line given by a linewise motion
function! s:LineReplace(type)
  if a:type !=# 'line'
    return
  endif
  ']move '[
  -delete_
endfunction
nnoremap lr :set operatorfunc=<SID>LineReplace<cr>g@
```

For more help see:

```
:h :d
:h :m
:h :range
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually realized my function had a big flaw (doesn't support upward motions).

Answer (score 0):

@xaizek is right; the correct way is to store the mark from the motion:

```
" replace the current line with a line given by a linewise motion
function! s:LineReplace(type)
  if a:type !=# 'line'
    return
  endif
  let lnum = getpos("']")[1]
  let saved_register = @@
  silent execute "normal S\<esc>my" . lnum . "Gdd'yPjddk^ :delmarks y"
  let @@ = saved_register
endfunction
nnoremap lr :set operatorfunc=<SID>LineReplace<cr>g@
```